# An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the StartTranscriptionJob operation: The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

Getting this error when trying to create a Transcription Job via AWS client. I have attached the following policy to the IAM user of the aws account.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "transcribe:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Ensured that the bucket name provided correctly and the user also has s3FullAccess policy attached. Below is the code

```
        self.aws_obj.start_transcription_job(
                TranscriptionJobName=job_name,
                Media={'MediaFileUri': s3_url},
                MediaFormat='wav',
                OutputBucketName='<bucket_name>',
                Settings={},
                LanguageCode='en-US')
```